# How to scrape card details using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapinghub

I am trying to scrape this link : https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card

Using the following code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re

axis_url = ["https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card"]

html = requests.get(axis_url[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

for d in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(d.get_text())
```

Output :

```
close
5.15%
%
4.00%
%
5.40%
```

Basically I want to get the details of each and every card present in that page

[image]

I have tried different tags but none of them seems to be working out.

I'd be happy to see the code that satisfies my requirement.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want for each card detail due  you also need the title like Get Unlimited Cashback?

Comment: @NoobCoder I don't want the titles I want just the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

your main issue is, that the website serve its content dynamically and you wont get your goal, the wa you are requesting it. Print your soup and take a look, it will not contain the elements you are inspecting in the browser.

### How to fix?

Use selenium that can deal with the dynamically generated content and will provide the information you have inspected:

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    
driver.close()

textList = []
for d in soup.select('#ulCreditCard li li > span'):
        textList.append(d.get_text('^^', strip=True))
    
textList
```

Comment: Thanks for your apt reply, could you please explain me as to what this selector is doing '#ulCreditCard li li > span'

Comment: Happy to help - You can still work with your selection, but it is not that specific as the [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that is pointing to the `ul` with id `ulCreditCard` and its `li`s with `li`s in it